# How to show custom error message when register fails ? (Express, Vue, Axios)

Tags: api, express, vue.js

Here is my problem, i made the entire registering system, and i made a check :

If the phone number or email entered is already in database, then i do a return of the status plus a custom string.

My question is, how can i display this error in vuejs?

API

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const experimentation = await loadExperimentationCollection();

    let experimentations = await experimentation.findOne({ mail: req.body.email });
    let phones = await experimentation.findOne({ phone: req.body.phone });

    if(experimentations){
        return res.status(400).send("Email already registered");
    }else if(phones){
        return res.status(400).send("Phone already taken")
    }
    else{
        await experimentation.insertOne({
            lastName: req.body.lastname,
            firstName: req.body.firstname,
            mail: req.body.email,
            phone: req.body.phone,
            address: req.body.address,
            city: req.body.city,
            zip: req.body.zip
        })
    }
})
```

VueJS script

```
methods: {
      async createExperimentation(){
        await ExperimentationService.insertExperimentation(this.firstname, this.lastname, this.email, this.phone, this.address, this.city, this.zip)
        this.experimentations = await ExperimentationService.getExperimentations();
      },
```

VueJS template

```
 <v-card ref="form">
      <v-alert type="success">
        HERE I WANNA DISPLAY THE SUCCESS MESSAGE
    </v-alert>
    <v-alert type="error">
        HERE I WANNA DISPLAY THE ERROR MESSAGE
    </v-alert>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `async/await`. You should use `try catch` to handle the error return from your API.

```js
methods: {
      async createExperimentation(){
        try {
          const response = await ExperimentationService.insertExperimentation(this.firstname, this.lastname, this.email, this.phone, this.address, this.city, this.zip);
          this.successMessage = response.data;
          this.experimentations = await ExperimentationService.getExperimentations();
        } catch (e) {
          this.errorMessage = e;
        }
      },
```

```html
 <v-card ref="form">
      <v-alert type="success">
        {{ successMessage }}
    </v-alert>
    <v-alert type="error">
        {{ errorMessage }}
    </v-alert>
```

I am not sure what does `insertExperimentation` and `getExperimentations` do. I tried my best.

Comment: I've tried it, but it returns me "Error: Request failed with status code 400", i want to display which field is the error :/

Comment: @dl3c01n What are you using? Axios or request module

Comment: Axios, but it displays the successMessage even the first time we get on the page :/

Comment: Fixed, but now, when i show the error, is displays me "Request failed with status code 409", even if i do "this.errorMessage = err.error" or "this.errorMessage = err.data"

Comment: Working thank you, last question, when requests is good and everything is inserting inside mongodb, should i `return res.status(200).send("you're registered")` ? If yes, how to get the data too ? `response.data`

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check the `const response` and `this.successMessage`. If my answer helped. Please mark it as an answer (:

Comment: So everything is working ! Thank you a lot, marked as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sweet alert](https://sweetalert.js.org/) to show pop up messages for success and failure. It's simple to use in Vue.

you have to use the Vue wrapper of the sweet alert and follow the instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sweetalert2).

After npm install do following --

- Import the module in main.js `import swal from './assets/plugins/sweetAlert2'`
- Let Vue know about the swal pluging by calling `Vue.use(swal)` in main.js.
- Import the plugin in component you want to use `import Swal from 'sweetalert2'`
- Call the swal with error or success message respectively `Swal('', '', 'error')` or `Swal('', response.data.message, 'success')` as required.
- No html changes are required, you can remove the `v-alert` from you html.